# How to expose database view in WebAPI Odata V4

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have imported view from database to edmx and added [Key] attribute to model POCO class:

namespace TFOMS.Domain.Model

```
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class vw_Tariffs_PR
    {

        public int TariffId { get; set; }
        public string MCOD { get; set; }
        public string OrgName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IDPR { get; set; }
        public string PRNAME { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IDSP { get; set; }
        public string SPNAME { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> isChild { get; set; }
        public decimal tariff { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DATEBEG { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DATEEND { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need to expose this view in webapi odata controller, but when I add following code to WebApiConfig.cs

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<vw_Tariffs_PR>("vw_Tariffs_PR");
            var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: "odata",
            model: model);

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

But when I start application I receive error: 
{"The entity 'vw_Tariffs_PR' does not have a key defined."} 
in
var model = builder.GetEdmModel();

After I add [Key] attribute to TariffId property I receive error in:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Код, выполняемый при запуске приложения
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        **GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);**
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);            
    }
}
```

In line GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
{"ValueFactory try to get acces to property Value of this instance."}

Can anybody explain how to expose view in odata controller, what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the sequence of routes in  WebApiConfig.cs, odata routes must be after webapi routes:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            // Web API configuration and services
            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<vw_Tariffs_PR>("vw_Tariffs_PR");
            var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: "odata",
            model: model);

        }
    }
```